# jQuery UI Autocomplete - how do I get the user entered value

Tags: jquery, user-interface, autocomplete

Disclaimer: I have gone through the related questions, and could not find solutions to this particular issue.

Scenario is this:

Based on whether the user selected a suggestion from the dropdown or if there are no matches, I want to execute different jQuery ajax actions. How do I do this? The place where I am stuck is how to capture the input that is currently in the autocomplete input text box?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest I'm not sure. Looking at the documentation the *search* event should work.

**Edit** It really helps to read documentation. :D

Search method.

> Triggers a search event, which, when
>   data is available, then will display
>   the suggestions; can be used by a
>   selectbox-like button to open the
>   suggestions when clicked. If no value
>   argument is specified, the current
>   input's value is used. Can be called
>   with an empty string and minLength: 0
>   to display all items.

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   search: function(event, ui) {
     $.ajax{
       //Your ajax parameters...

       success: function(data) { //No idea what format your data is in...
         if(data['status'] == false) { //there is no result
           //return your data.
           //Trigger the events you want if the item does no exist.
         }
         else if(data['status'] == true){
            //return data normally.
         }
       }

     }
   }
});
```

Comment: I have the change event hooked up, and for testing, I put an alert box in there. Does not seem to have any effect :(

Comment: Hopefully search will work for you. Basically I just put an if statement in the ajax object. You could probably do the same if you use $.ajax in the search option.

Answer (score 2):

To capture the input that is currently in the autocomplete input text box you could use the `select` method as in the [autocomplete remote example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote):

```
    $("#birds").autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            log(ui.item ? ("Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id) : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        }
    });
```

If `ui.item` has a value, it means that something has matched (and the matched value is in there).

And if you want what the user has typed then use `this.value`.

Comment: My select looks like this:

select: function (event, ui) {
    var normalText = ui.item ? ui.item.label.replace(/(<.+?>)/gi, '') : $(this).value;
    var myTargetUrl = "CreateNew/CreateNew?newTitle=" + normalText;
    $('#<%= id %>').val(normalText);

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: myTargetUrl
    });
    alert(myTargetUrl);
    return false;
    }

But the alert dialog never comes up, when I enter a value that does not exist and press <ENTER>

At what point do I have access to the entered value, I have tried search event, change event etc to no avail

Comment: I don't know why the alert does not appear. Maybe the ajax call is throwing an exception. But I made a sample here and it does appear http://jsbin.com/aqewu4/edit (even when the ajax call points to nothing). Maybe that sample page can help you work out the problem. If not, edit your question with more details or create a new question.