# jQuery Dropdown set Value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

i have a JQuery UI dropdown. Actually i have 2.

I select in the first one something, set a checkbox on true. In the .change() of that checkbox i want to copy the selected value from the first dropdown to the second one.

with `$('#drop_1').val()` i get the selected value.

i thought i can set it with `$('#drop_1').val($('#drop_2').val())`. Sadly this only works with normal dropdowns. 
Is there a way to set the value like this:

```
$('#drop_1').find('option:selected').text();
```

Any idea how can i do this?

This did the trick and it works now. The value was set, but it wasnt shown in the UI.

```
var selected_campaign = $('#campaign_id').val();
$('#follow_campaign_id').val(selected_campaign);
$('#follow_campaign_id').next().find('input.ui-combobox-input').val($('#follow_campaign_id').children('option[value=' +selected_campaign+ ']').html());
```

**FIXED**

Comment: Can you show us a ([minimal/SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you're working with/doing? Also, add any relevant code to the question, that it "only works with normal dropdowns" suggests that there's something jQuery/jQuery UI dependent going on.

Comment: as i know, there is no jquery ui dropdown

Comment: @Ravi, May be OP is talking about jQuery ui  Autocomplete..

Comment: yes it is an autocomplete (a dropwdown)

Comment: can you describe your problem more precisely ? Do you mean you have 2 selects, which you wrapped in an autocomplete widget, as per the demo http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrapped your `select` in a jquery-ui `autocomplete` widget :

The original selects will be hidden, the displayed html is an input.

You need to also set the value of this input :

```
function(){
    var newval = $('#drop_1').val();

    $('#drop_2').val( newval );
    //you will have to find the correct selector for your particular settings here.
    //I base this code on the jquery-ui demo (see link below) :
    var $input = $('#drop_2').sibling('span.ui-combobox').find('input');
    $input.val(newval);
}
```

[jquery-ui demo](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) for combobox widget

Answer (score 1):

> Never mind, missed the UI part of the questing, following is for HTML  only.

The API-docs of JQuery are quite good for these kind of things: http://api.jquery.com/val/ .
Having said that, this should do the trick:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setDrop2() {
// only change if checkbox is true
if ($('#check_1').is(':checked')) {
    $("#drop_2").val($("#drop_1").val());
}
}
</script>

<select id="drop_1">
  <option>option_1</option><option>option_2</option><option>option_3</option>
</select> drop_1  
<input type="checkbox" id="check_1" value="check1" onchange="javascript:setDrop2()"/> check_1
<select id="drop_2">
  <option>option_1</option><option>option_2</option><option>option_3</option>
</select> drop_2
```

Comment: Have you checked these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422235/jquery-autocomplete-get-selected-item-text or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367686/jquery-ui-autocomplete-how-do-i-get-the-user-entered-value ?

Answer (score 0):

The  tag does not have any siblings so the code will bomb if you try to get to the input using the sibling attribute. Hit the parent and then search for a span containing the input like this:

```
$("#drop-2").parent().find("span input").val($("#drop_1");
```